# Generate sample XML from JAXB using Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Let's say I've created JAXB class in eclipse. (Using @XmlRootElement, @XmlAttribute, etc)

Is there a plugin which generate me example XML preview from my JAXB annotated class ?

Answer (score 1):

There are XML Editors, which can create Sample XMLs from the XSD, for example we use Altova XMLSpy.

Comment: I am looking for some free software. Non commercial use.

Comment: have you tried this http://www.freewarebox.com/free_1133_xmlspy-home-edition-download.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called " org.jvnet.jaxbw.eclipse_1.0.0" which you need to keep in eclipse lib folder.

Below is the link for guide.

http://www.xyzws.com/scdjws/studyguide/jaxb_samples2.0.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JAXB marshaller** for doing this. Just a 3 three lines of code.

> ```
>         File file = new File("D:\\generatedFile.xml");
>         JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Myclass.class);
>         Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();  
>         jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);  
>         jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, file);
> ```

generatedFile.xml will contains the XML equivalent of your annonated java bean(Myclass)